# PHP Register Script - Not working

Tags: php, mysql, scripting

I just made a register script from scratch, but I'm still going to improve it. Basically I'm testing it first before I improve it - somehow, it doesn't work...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $username = mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['login']));
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $vpassword = $_POST['vpassword'];
   $email = mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
   $vemail = mysql_escape_string($trim($_POST['vemail']));

   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $date = date("jS F Y");

if(!empty($username) || !empty($password) || !empty($vpassword) || !empty($email) || !empty($vemail))
{
    if($password == $vpassword && $email == $vemail)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE username='" . $username . "'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_affected_rows($result) == 1)
        {
            echo "The account already exists!";
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO members
                    (username, password, email, ip, level, type, signed, hide, hidemail, avatar, notes)
                    VALUES('" . $username . "', '" . $password . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $ip . "', '0', '0', '" . $date . "', '1', '1', '', '')";

            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Please check the fields so that they match";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Check the missing fields!";
}

if($result)
{
    echo "Account created successfully!";
}
else
{
    echo "Error creating account";
}
}
```

What could be wrong about this...?

Help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Could you explain what exactly does not work?

Comment: I think your conditional should be && instead of ||

Comment: sshow is right!

You may also try to echo the resulting INSERT query and issue the command directly to your database, you may discover that the error is not in PHP but in the SQL query. Maybe the 'date' field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking if one of the values is not empty when you use `||`. Use `&&` instead and. This way you are not allowing any field to be empty. So:

`if(!empty($username) || !empty($password) || ...`

This means "if any of these is not empty". Use this instead:

`if(!empty($username) && !empty($password) && ...`

Which means "if there are no empty fields".

Comment: Ok, I changed it... but when I submit the register, it just shows blank, white, nothingness :(

I have this for my database table:

CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` bigint(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: As this database above, I edited it and the PHP script after posting this to see if it works, turned out it didn't